# How to add multiple conditions in do-while loop?

Tags: c++

How to add both string red and blue in while(). I add them as

```
while(color!="red"||"blue");.
```

When I run this code it points out an error, please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

You have three problems. First, you need to do this:

```
while(color!="red" || color!="blue");
```

Then remove the semi-colon because otherwise you'll have a hanging code block.

Next, `||` is the wrong operator here. It should be and instead:

```
while(color!="red" && color!="blue")
```

If you think about it logically, you need both predicates to be true. So an or would not be appropriate here.

Comment: It's a `do-while` in the post.

Comment: nothing is wrong in do part of the loop,i just want to add those strings in while() and i need only one of them at a time.

Comment: @Mike, @LogicStuff's correct statement makes your 3rd line "*Then remove the semicolon because otherwise you'll have a hanging code block."* incorrect.  A `while()` of a `do-while` loop is indeed followed by a `;`.  You should consider editing that part.